# Best way to find functions with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Hey guys I'm working with a custom scripting language and I am making a sort of IDE for this language in C#. In this language the functions are defined like this:

```
yourfunctionhere(possiblepararmhere)
{
  yourcodehere;
}
```

I've been trying to figure out the best way to get a list of all the functions via regex and couldn't find a working way to get a list of all the defined functions. Could somebody tell me of a better way or a way to do it with regex? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Would something like this work in C#? `%[a-z_0-9^[^]*]++ [a-z_0-9*^[^]]+[ ^t]++[a-z_0-9*^[^]]+[ ^t]++^([*a-z_0-9]+^)[ ^t]++([^p*&, ^t^[^]a-z_0-9./(!]++)[~;]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: If you are serious about your language, you should use a lexer/parser pair, not regex.

Comment: I may do this, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a list of function names something like this might work:

```
Regex.Matches(source,@"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*\([^()]*\)\s*{").Cast<Match>()
    .Select (m => m.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value).ToArray()
```

Basically, that regex is looking for any group of alphanumeric characters, followed by optional white space, followed an open parenthesis, followed by zero or more non-parentheses, followed by a close parenthesis, followed by optional white space, and then an open curly brace.

Then from there you extract just the beginning portion, and create a list. Assuming the language does not otherwise allow a close parenthesis to be followed by an open curly bracket, then the above should work. Otherwise more details would be needed.

Comment: I should note that the above may catch commented out functions, and would catch anything that looks like a function defintion in a string. The best way to go is to have a parser. They are not really that hard to make especially if there exists formal documentation of the language in question. If the specification includes a grammar in BNF or something similar, the job becomes a pretty straightforward translation.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be much easier if you changed your syntax by adding a reserved keyword like 'def', so your declarations become:

```
def yourfunctionhere(possiblepararmhere)
{
    yourcodehere;
}
```

Then you can use a simple regex like `def [a-zA-Z0-9]+`.

Comment: I too was thinking this. That is the reason I was having such a difficult time. Unfortunately I do not have the ability to change the scripting language.

Comment: Also that simple regex wouldn't work (think about "def ..." in a string literal).  The dragon book (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) is the authority on this subject really.

Answer (score -1):

```
var pat=  @"\b(public|private|internal|protected)\s*" + @"\b(static|virtual|abstract)?\s*[a-zA-Z_]*(?<method>\s[a-zA-Z_]+\s*)" + @"\((([a-zA-Z_\[\]\<\>]*\s*[a-zA-Z_]*\s*)[,]?\s*)+\)" ;
```